# Create IndexedBase which contains only real values

Tags: sympy

Is it somehow possible to create an IndexedBase with all elements being real valued? Like

```py
k = sympy.IndexedBase('k', real = True))
```

Line above doesn't work. Sympy always assumes IndexedBase as complex:

```py
 In [9]: import sympy

         k= sympy.IndexedBase('k')

         sympy.expand_complex(1/k)

 Out[9]: 
            re(k)            ⅈ⋅im(k)    
       ─────────────── - ───────────────
         2        2        2        2   
       re (k) + im (k)   re (k) + im (k)
```

Setting k to real would help me to simplify a long expression... Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present it is not possible to make assumptions about indexed objects: [SymPy issue #13992](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13992). By the way, an IndexedBase `k` by itself should not normally appear in expressions: I would expect to see `k[j]` where `j` is some index.

A workaround is to use Function syntax. After all, an IndexedBase object is (mathematically) just a function that takes an integer argument; the difference is only between subscript notation and parentheses notation for the argument.

```
k = Function('k', real=True)
j = Idx('j')
expand_complex(1/k(j))   #  1/k(j)
```